# Best choice. Use .Net Dll in Java Application

Tags: java, .net, java-native-interface, jna, jni4net

I know three is some questions about this, but I've not found the exact response.
We have a .Net dll (C#) with no dependencies or p/Invoke. So it's a full .net platform library.
One of our clientes wants to use it in a Java Application.

What's the best choice?
I've been looking at jni4net wich could be a perfect solution, but it seems don't support generics in .Net (our dll uses lot of generics dictionaries and collections)

It's JNA the best choice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem several years ago. I had a dll written in Delphi. (Delphi was a Pascal-based Windows app development tool sold by Borland.) I needed to call the dll from Java, but some of the dll functionss had parameters and return types that that were incompatible with Java. (As an interesting, if irrelevant, aside, Anders Hejlsberg, who invented C# for Microsoft, also invented Delphi for Borland.) Here is how I solved the problem.

1) I did use jni to allow my Java code to call a dll.

2) I wrote a thin wrapper dll in Delphi that was the actual dll called by my Java jni code. For those functions that were completely compatible with Java, the wrapper dll simply acted as a pass though, directly calling the actual dll functions and returning the return value. For those functions that were not compatible, the wrapper dll defined corresponding methods that were compatible with Java and did the appropriate translation from Java to Delphi before calling the actual dll.

3) I also wrote a thin wrapper object above my jni calls. Again, for the most part, the java wrapper directly made jni calls for those functions that were completely compatible between Java and Delphi. However, in my case, a few functions required that I pass in Delphi objects. So, what I did was define corresponding Java objects. The main purpose of my Java wrapper object was to take these Java objects, translate them into parameters that were compatible with my Delphi wrapper dll, and then make the apprropriate jni call. Also, for those dll functions which passed back an object, my java wrapper took the java-compatible return value from the jni call, and created and asssembled the appropriate object.

This may sound like a lot of work, but it really was not (and my dll had over 100 methods, and a dozen or so Delphi object types). When I was done, writing the Java application code that actually used the dll was very straight forward.

Regarding the generics, that could be a problem. But, if in real life, the number of object types you support is relatively small (and it often is), you can just write separate calls for each object type in your wrapper. (That is what those of us who remember Java 2 used to do before they invented generics and it worked just fine, even if it was a bit less elegant.) Your application Java code could stll use generics; the wrapper would make the appropriate call based on the actual type that was passed in.

Hopefully this will give you some ideas on how you might proceed.

Comment: Well explained, this is similar to my own experience bridging between Delphi and Java.  I have also used [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to bridge between Java and C++ dlls and this may be a solution as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420617/accessing-net-dll-libraries-components-from-java)

Answer (score 1):

To use .NET DLL in JAVA I would say that the best choice is to go with native bridge like Javonet. With such bridge all you have to do is just copy .NET dll to your JAVA project folder and load it with one method call and use the .NET objects like they were JAVA objects. You skip the whole native part and get a lot of built-in tools for data types conversion, subscribing events, garbage collector, exceptions and many others.

**Sample code to use "Your.dll" could look like this:**

```
Javonet.addReference("Your.dll");
NObject yourDotNetObject = Javonet.New("MyDotNetClass");
yourDotNetObject.invoke("FooMethod", arg1, arg2);

//out of the box you get also support for all types, arrays, generics etc
yourDotNetObject.generic(Javonet.getType("String")).invoke("Foo", "sample");
//such code could call following .NET method passing String as T
//void Foo<T>(T arg);
```

So as you see with semi-reflection syntax you get access to whole .NET world including any custom DLL or .NET framework classes. Manual solution is good but rather for learning then using in real project as it could take more time to solve all issue then your whole project needs ;)

For more samples check this:
http://www.javonet.com/quick-start-guide/