# calling a dll file in a Java EE application on linux

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, dll, redhat

I have a Java web application using struts, Hibernate and spring running on redhat. I am going to search about calling a dll file in my application, its vulnerabilities and consequences. could any one help me about the problems and bugs or errors or maybe it is not possible to do that.

Comment: Linux don't have DLL, it has dynamic libraries thru shared objects `.so` files.

Comment: So you will at least need to recompile on Linux the source code producing that `.dll` file on Windows, to get a `.so` file on Linux. You probably may need to patch the source code if it is using Windows specific functions or constructs.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to your Help Microsoft gives a way to call DLL using JNI
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222092

Apart from this you can look at the previous posts at 
[How do I call dll inside Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771145/how-do-i-call-dll-inside-java)

IBM tutorial on JNI will also prove to be useful
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/

To run the dll in Linux environment you might need emulators like [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) or [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/). But I cannot assure you of success because both Wine and Crossover are not 100% windows compliant.

Comment: thanks for your help, but more accurate I want to know about the problems it may cause to guess that it is efficient or not.

Comment: A previous posts talks about that too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050746/best-choice-use-net-dll-in-java-application